# Help with solving 2 integrals - one definite and one indefinite

Tags: definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I need help with solving these two integrals:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
&\int_{ -\pi /4}^{ \pi /4} \frac{x^7-x+1}{\cos^2 x}\mathrm dx \\
&\int \frac{\sin^2(x)}{\sin(x)+2\cos(x)}\mathrm dx 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: The first integral is just 2 since you can throw away the odd part.

Comment: for the second integral use the tan-half angle substitution

Comment: Second integral is just $\int \dfrac{\sin^2 x}{\sin (x + y)}\, dx = \dfrac{\left(\cos\left(2y\right)-1\right)\left(\ln\left(\cos\left(x+y\right)+1\right)-\ln\left(1-\cos\left(x+y\right)\right)\right)}{4}-\cos\left(x-y\right)+C$.

Comment: use that $$\sin(x)=2\,{\frac {\tan \left( x/2 \right) }{1+ \left( \tan \left( x/2 \right) \right) ^{2}}}
$$ and $$\cos(x)={\frac {1- \left( \tan \left( x/2 \right) \right) ^{2}}{1+ \left( \tan \left( x/2 \right) \right) ^{2}}}
$$

Comment: @Guy Fsone can you please elaborate?

Comment: integral of odd function over symmetric domain is zero

Comment: why did you change post?

Comment: I reverted an edit someone else had made that basically removed the entire first question. Not good form when others have already answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Second  one @Dr Sonnhard already give a sufficient hint.

For the First one observe that

$$\int_{ -\pi /4}^{ \pi /4} \frac{x^7-x+1}{\cos^2 x}\mathrm dx =\int_{ -\pi /4}^{ \pi /4} \frac{1}{\cos^2 x}\mathrm dx 
 =\int_{ -\pi /4}^{ \pi /4} (\tan x)'dx =2
$$

Given that

$$\int_{ -\pi /4}^{ \pi /4} \frac{x^7-x}{\cos^2 x}\mathrm dx =0$$ since the integral is over a symetric domain and the integrand is an odd function.

also note that $$ (\tan x)'= 1+\tan ^2x =\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}$$

Comment: Your "first one" integral is OPs second integral.

Comment: I understand what you mean by OPS